# Unity/C#: I can not work out why this variable doesn't exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This the entirety of my code because this problem is completely confusing me:

```
public class Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float stalls;
    public float IntegerYVelocity;
    public float TotalJumpForce;
    public float TotalDropForce;
    public float jumps;
    public float speed;
    public float jumpForce;
    public float dropforce;
    bool isGrounded = false;
    public Transform isGroundedChecker;
    public float checkGroundRadius;
    public LayerMask groundLayer;

    Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        TotalJumpForce = rb.velocity.y + jumpforce;
        TotalDropForce = rb.velocity.y + dropforce;
        CheckIfGrounded();
        Move();
        Jump();
        Drop();
        Stall();
    }
    void Move()
    {
        float x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float moveBy = x * speed;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveBy, rb.velocity.y);
    }
    void Jump()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("w"))
        {
            if (jumps > 0)
                    rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, TotalJumpForce);
                    jumps = jumps - 1;
        }
    }
    void Drop()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("s"))
        {

            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, TotalDropForce);
        }
    }
    void CheckIfGrounded()
    {
        Collider2D collider = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(isGroundedChecker.position, checkGroundRadius, groundLayer);
        if (collider != null)
        {
            isGrounded = true;
            jumps = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            isGrounded = false;
        }
    }
    void Stall()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("q"))
        {
            if (stalls > 0)
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 0);
            stalls = stalls - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

But then i get this compiler error:

```
Assets\Controller.cs(29,42): error CS0103: The name 'jumpforce' does not exist in the current context
```

Which is confusing me because everything was fine until I added the stall void.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to capitalize the "F" in "jumpForce" on line 29.

Comment: Thank you, how the hell did I miss that!